# String convertion in java with inbuilt string function

Tags: java, string, data-structures

How do i convert a string like below

```
String str="[in,us,eu,af,th]";
```

into

```
["in","us","eu","af","th"]
```

Comment: Try `str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","").split(",")`

Comment: You are allowed to do that in many ways. Go ahead.

Comment: @Thomas I tried !!but  It gave error http://ideone.com/2uDRsa

Comment: What you linked is not what I suggested and there's also no hint of an error ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String result = str.replace("[", "[\"").replace(",", "\",\"").replace("]", "\"]");
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use String functions:

```
str = str.substring(1,str.length()-2); // remove brackets
String a[] = str.split(","); //split it.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "[in,us,eu,af,th]";

    str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);

    // #1 remove starting and ending brackets
    System.out.println("String without brackets : " + str);

    //#2 split by comma
    String[] stringTokens = str.split(",");
    StringBuffer outputStrBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    outputStrBuffer.append("["); // append starting square bracket

    for (int i = 0; i <= stringTokens.length - 1; i++) {
        //prefix and postfix each token with double quote
        outputStrBuffer.append("\"");
        outputStrBuffer.append(stringTokens[i]);
        outputStrBuffer.append("\"");

        // for last toke dont append comma at end
        if (i != stringTokens.length - 1) {
            outputStrBuffer.append(",");
        }
    }
    outputStrBuffer.append("]"); // append ending square bracket

    System.out.println("String prefixed & postfixed with double quotes, separated by comma : " + outputStrBuffer.toString());
}
```

Comment: Output of above code:
String prefixed & postfixed with double quotes, separated by comma : ["in","us","eu","af","th"]

Comment: You might add that to your answer instead of a comment and probably also some description on how that code works and why it is done like this.